# Use same definition for two ControlTemplates

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a definition of some visual elements that I want to use for two differnt controls (Button, Thumb). Is there a way two get rid of duplicate code?

```
   <Style x:Key="HorizontalSliderThumbStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
this block is the same -->  <Grid>
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                   ...
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="borderRect" Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
                                   ...


    <Style x:Key="KeyboardButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
this block is the same -->  <Grid>
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    ...
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="borderRect" Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
                                   ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="SharedControlTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Shared Control Template"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}" x:Key="HorizontalSliderThumbStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SharedControlTemplate}"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="KeyboardButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SharedControlTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

Both `Thumb` and `Button` derive from the base class of `Control` (not immediately, but it's one of the ancestors).  So if you define a `ControlTemplate` for it, you may give both controls the same template.  Then, in style, you'll tailor their individual behavior, if that's what you need.

Use example:

```
<Thumb Style="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderThumbStyle}" BorderBrush="AliceBlue"/>
<Button Style="{StaticResource KeyboardButtonStyle}" BorderBrush="Aquamarine"/>
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

In the comments you've mentioned that you wanted to use a `ContentPresenter` in the `ControlTemplate`.  You'll have to bind to the `Content` property of a `ContentControl`.  Since not every `Control` is a `ContentControl`, it will work only for those `Controls` that contain actual content... but if it doesn't have content, no errors will occur.  Here's the change:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="SharedControlTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Shared Control Template"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Note that I added one line for the `ContentPresenter` that binds to the content of a `ContentControl`.  If you want to add some sort of content, it'll accept it:

```
<Thumb Style="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderThumbStyle}" BorderBrush="AliceBlue"/>
<Button Style="{StaticResource KeyboardButtonStyle}" BorderBrush="Aquamarine">
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="20"/>
</Button>
```

[image]

Comment: @B.K helps me a lot. Thanks

Comment: @B.K. what if I use a ContentPresenter in this Template? It seams it doesn't work in the Button.

Comment: @GreenEyedAndy I think I figured out something... let me know if that's what you're shooting for.  Check the edit to my answer.

Comment: @B.K. This is it! I'll never understand this syntax ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a `DataTemplate` to define the inner controls and then use the [`ContentControl` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) to render them in each `ControlTemplate`. Try this:

In `Resources`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="InnerContent">
    <!-- Define your inner content here -->
</DataTemplate>
```

...

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource InnerContent}" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

...

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource InnerContent}" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

I can't check right now, but if that doesn't work, a `ContentPresenter` with the same properties set should.

Comment: Thank you, for that - but the inner Controls use TemplateBinding Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" for example. And obviously this isn't working. I edited my question to clearify this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base style

```
<Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
                 ...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and derive your style from it using `BasedOn`

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
        ...        
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you, this would be working also but B.K. answered earlier.